# VMware ESXi config pass-through for Fibre Channel

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, fibre-channel

I want to config pass-through for FC in VMware ESXi 5.5 (FC HBA: `ISP2532-based 8Gb Fibre Channel to PCI Express HBA`) follow the link https://tinkertry.com/usb3passthru. But when I turn on the virtual machine, I receive error:

```
Failed to start the virtual machine.
Failed to register the device pciPassthru0 for 10:0.1 due to unavailable hardware or software support
```

Do you know where the error come from?

Comment: What EXACT model of FC HBA, CPU/s and system-board do you have - only specific combinations are supported.

Comment: I think this error mainly involve in software, the model is ISP2532-based 8Gb Fibre Channel to PCI Express HBA

Comment: What server do you have?

Comment: Oh and presumably you've enabled VT-D in your BIOS?

Comment: My server is HP ProLiant ML350p Generation 8. About VT-D, I have still not checked it yet.

Comment: There was a passthrough issue on some HP servers with unpatched 5.5, are you up to date with your patching?

Comment: Thank you very much for your information. I will check VT-D in BIOS, then reinstall another version of ESXi

Comment: If the problem has to do with HPE-specific drivers and you use VUM you don't have to reinstall ESXi, you can add http://vibsdepot.hpe.com/ (http://vibsdepot.hpe.com/hpq/latest/index.xml and/or http://vibsdepot.hpe.com/hpq/latest/index-drv.xml I'm not sure right now) as a software repository and just update. Btw: Sometimes there are also firmware problems so make sure you're on a current firmware version, too.

Answer (score 1):

My problem actually come from version of Vmware ESXi. After reinstall ESXi 5.5 U3, this error has gone.